# How to automatically run chkdsk on startup after forceful shutdown/powerloss

Tags: windows, boot, shutdown, windows-10-preview, chkdsk

How can I (in Windows 10) run checkdisk (chkdsk /f) automatically on boot after a forceful shutdown/powerloss.

My Purpose:
Forceful shutdown/powerloss are the one (and mostly only?) reason I know which can cause filesystem errors, and I prefer to get those errors fixed immediately rather than building on top of something bad, to avoid further errors.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this when Microsoft have spent years and millions of dollars researching and developing chkdsk to do what it already does for both desktops/laptops and for business critical servers?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to change anything?  I'm not familiar with Win 10, but this used to be done automatically whenever the computer was not shut down gracefully.

Comment: I use win 10 and it crashes all the time or force me to do forceful shutdown. After several such I scan disks and find errors, and fix them and afterwards recent changes seem to be gone. I may be wrong about recent changes being lost, but I'm not wrong about windows not automatically fixing my disks on boot-up. MS may have different criteria than me, I'm willing to wait 5mins extra on every boot after forcefull shutdown, but MS may judge that is not what everybody wants. I have same experince from win7+win8.